# How to solve this strange random error in jasmin UNIT test cases?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

When running jasmin unit test cases I got this error randomly (once in 3 time) and that fails all the test cases.

```
Cannot read property 'classList' of null\n    at <Jasmine>\n  at webpack:///path-to-component/component.ts:33:53 <- karma-test-shim.9578926fa4f5e11a1233db2d090778ef.bundle.js:226810:45263\n    at callSubscriberWithDelayedExceptions 

(webpack:///node_modules/pubsub-js/src/pubsub.js:62 <- karma-test-shim.9578926fa4f5e11a1233db2d090778ef.bundle.js:195654:13)\n    at deliverMessage (webpack:///node_modules/pubsub-js/src/pubsub.js:83 <- karma-test-shim.9578926fa4f5e11a1233db2d090778ef.bundle.js:195675:17)\n    at deliverNamespaced
```

I understand that there is something wrong here in this two functions but I am not sure what is wrong here?

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.aFunction();
    this.sub = PubSub.subscribe('someParam', (subId, Identifier: string) => {
      document.querySelector(Identifier).classList.add('highlight');
      setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector(Identifier).classList.remove('highlight');
      }, 2000);
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.aParam= false;
    /*  Few functions  */
  }
```

Here are two test cases which involved above function

```
  it('should load without any input', () => {
    spyOn(document, 'querySelector').and.callFake(function () {
      return {
        value: true,
        classList: {
          remove: () => { },
          add: () => { },
        }
      };
    });
    expect(component.customized).toBe(undefined);
  });


  it('should load with basic input attributes', () => {
    component.customized = { someEntity: true };
    spyOn(document, 'querySelector').and.callFake(function () {
      return {
        value: true,
        classList: {
          remove: () => { },
          add: () => { },
          contains: () => { }
        }
      };
    });
    fixture.autoDetectChanges();
    componentInstance.ngOnChanges(null);
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(something).toBe(true);
    });
  });
```

I have doubt that it is related to subscription and fakeAsync (which I have not applied) cause its failing randomly.

Can you please let me know what is wrong in test cases?

Comment: mocking ` document.querySelector(Identifier)` is not what you should do, Can you show more info about `PubSub.subscribe` and its associated component code.

Comment: Hey Shashank, PubSub.subscribe is an interface 
    interface Subscribe{
        subscribe(message: any, func: Function): any;
    }

in pubsub library imported in angular project

Comment: Please provide more information on your component and your test setup and maybe try and recreate the issue in a stackblitz. Without this it‘s hard to tell.

Comment: ok sure I will do it soon :)

Comment: Here is recreation of that prob in simple manner
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64242278/how-to-write-test-cases-for-subscriber-and-timeout-inside-ngonit-method/64242699#64242699