# How to write test cases for Subscriber and timeout inside ngOnit method?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, publish-subscribe

I have a class in angular8 application with following ngOnit method

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setCustomizedValues();
    this.sub = PubSub.subscribe('highlightEntity', (subId, entityIdentifier: string) => {
      document.querySelector(entityIdentifier).classList.add('highlight');

      setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector(entityIdentifier).classList.remove('highlight');
      }, 2000);

    });
  }
```

I have initialised the following test case

```
describe('aComponent', () => {

    
  let httpCallerServiceStub = jasmine.createSpyObj('httpCallerServiceStub', ['get']);

  let fixture: ComponentFixture<aComponent>;
  let componentInstance: aComponent;
  localStorage.clear();
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [aComponent],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: HttpCallerService,
          useValue: httpCallerServiceStub
        }],
      imports: [CommonModule, CmcSpinnerModule, NgbModule],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(aComponent);
    componentInstance = fixture.componentRef.instance;
    fixture.autoDetectChanges();
  });

 describe('ngOnInit method', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      fixture.componentInstance.customized = {};
    });

    it('should initialize with minimum input', () => {
      // Triggers ngOnInit
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(fixture.componentInstance.customized).toEqual({});
    });
  });
```

So when I run this it randomly throwing the following error

```
 "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nTypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null\n    at <Jasmine>\n    at webpack:///components/aComponent/aComponent.ts:33:53
```

Here is console error in karma test runner,
[image]

and here is what the file suggest

[image]

So after this point however number of test I write ahead, the issue still remains the same, sometime it works, sometime it doesnt.

Can you please tell me what to do with pubsub.subscriber and timeout inside ngonit?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're messing with the `DOM`, `ngOnInit` can be too early for that. The `DOM` has not yet been painted. Try moving the logic to `ngAfterViewInit`

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.sub = PubSub.subscribe('highlightEntity', (subId, entityIdentifier: string) => {
      document.querySelector(entityIdentifier).classList.add('highlight');

      setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector(entityIdentifier).classList.remove('highlight');
      }, 2000);
    });
}
```

And to test the `setTimeout`, you can use `fakeAsync` and `tick`.

```
import { fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
...
it('should initialize with minimum input', fakeAsync(() => {
      // Triggers ngOnInit
      fixture.detectChanges();
      // do your assertions for ngAfterViewInit
      // make 2s pass in a fake way
      tick(2000);
      // do your assertions for the setTimeout callback
      expect(fixture.componentInstance.customized).toEqual({});
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks for your input So what if I can not change anything in component? Though I am following your suggestion of tick.

Comment: Also, Do i have to do anything related to pubsub?

Comment: Can you please tell me what did you mean by do assertions for ngAfterViewInit, it means to call it?

Comment: If you cannot change anything in the component, I think it's a bug in general. Right now you are facing a race condition because the `.subscribe` happens at a later point in time and the DOM could be ready, could not be. Try doing `      document.querySelector(entityIdentifier).classList.add('highlight');
` outside of the `subscribe`, I bet it will fail always. I see it's going inside of the subscribe of `PubSub` in your tests so I assume it is mocked correctly. You don't have to call `ngAfterViewInit`, Angular's lifecycle will take care of it (it should be called automatically).

Comment: ok thanks so tick of 2000ms working correctly, and also what is role of fixture when stable? do i need to apply it for assertions, second for other functions test cases I dont need tick of 2000ms (as ngonit wont be called everytime right?)

Comment: `fixture.whenStable` waits until all pending promises have completed and then continues with its assertions. I think for you, when you call `fixture.detectChanges` `ngOnInit` gets called so it is up to you. If the `setTimeout` remains in the `ngOnInit`, I think it would be good to have `fakeAsync` and `tick` for each test.

Comment: so now when I am using fdescribe, tests are running fine but when I run all the tests the same issue comes up again.  its little strange.